# Why is needed to check if GLAD or GLEW was initialized correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glew

I was setting up opengl using GLFW + GLAD or GLEW (`#include glad/glad.h` `#include <GL/glew.h>`).
After the function `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);` I need to check if GLAD or GLEW was initialized correctly or I will run into **exception errors** in Visual Studio 2019.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {

GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

/* Check if GLEW is ok after valid context */
/*if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
}*/
/* or Check if GLAD is ok after valid context */
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << endl;
    return -1;
}

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    ...
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

Here I am using GLAD. I really can't understand why I have to check this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here I am using GLAD. I really can't understand why I have to check this
>
> ```
> if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
> ```

The key point here is not the check, but the call to `gladLoadGLLoader` which actually initializes GLAD and loads all the GL function pointers. So what you do here is *initializing* GLAD, and just checking the *return value* of that function which tells you if GLAD was able to correctly initialize.

So if you don't want the "check", the correct code would be just

```
gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress);
```

Ommiting the check is of course not a good idea, because it means that you might attempt to call GL function pointers which might not be loaded, which will most likely crash your application - the same errors you will see when not even attempting to intialize it, as you already did.